# Replace doesn't work when a extra character is added

Tags: javascript, arrays, replace

As of my [Previous Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69053777/16711984) I figured out how i can replace multiple text in an array without calling `.replace` function many times

```js
const iconMap = {
    "ico.Win10": '<i class="fab fa-windows"></i>',
    "ico.Ubuntu": '<i class="fab fa-ubuntu"></i>',
    "ico.Whatsapp": '<i class="fab fa-whatsapp"></i>',
    "ico.Instagram": '<i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>',
    "ico.Google": '<i class="fab fa-google"></i>',
    "ico.Microsoft": '<i class="fab fa-microsoft"></i>',
    "ico.Twitter": '<i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>',
    "ico.Facebook": '<i class="fab fa-facebook"></i>',
}

var userText = "ico.Win10 + S";
var keysArray = userText.split("+").filter(e =>  String(e));
keysArray = $.map(keysArray, $.trim);



for (let i = 0; i < keysArray.length; i++) {
    if (iconMap[keysArray[i]] != undefined) {
        keysArray[i] = keysArray[i].replace(keysArray[i], iconMap[keysArray[i]])
    }
}

console.log(keysArray)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

But if my `userText` Variable changes to something like `"ico.Win10 Windows + S";`

I get output `["ico.Win10 Windows", "S"]` instead of `["<i class="fab fa-windows"></i> Windows", "S"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The duplicate that was flagged for you previous post indicated the use of [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) for the replace, which allow one to target specific patterns within a string.

You can apply this to your use case, searching for substrings that start with `ico.`. To allow for the possibility that there may be more than one such substring, the snippet below uses [`matchAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll) to iterate over all matches and  replace if there is a corresponding property in the `iconMap` lookup.

```js
const iconMap = { 'ico.Win10': '<i class="fab fa-windows"></i>', 'ico.Ubuntu': '<i class="fab fa-ubuntu"></i>', 'ico.Whatsapp': '<i class="fab fa-whatsapp"></i>', 'ico.Instagram': '<i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>', 'ico.Google': '<i class="fab fa-google"></i>', 'ico.Microsoft': '<i class="fab fa-microsoft"></i>', 'ico.Twitter': '<i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>', 'ico.Facebook': '<i class="fab fa-facebook"></i>', };

const replaceIco = (str) => {
  for (const [, ico] of str.matchAll(/(ico\..*?)\s/g)) {
    str = str.replace(ico, iconMap[ico] ?? ico);
  }

  return str;
};

const userText = 'ico.Whatsapp WhatsApp ico.Win10 Windows + S';

const keysArray = userText.split('+').map(replaceIco);

console.log(keysArray);
```

If you'd rather not use/learn RegExp then you can achieve the same thing using array methods by splitting the passed string at each `' '` and mapping over each word returning the values from the lookup table if they exist.

```js
const iconMap = { 'ico.Win10': '<i class="fab fa-windows"></i>', 'ico.Ubuntu': '<i class="fab fa-ubuntu"></i>', 'ico.Whatsapp': '<i class="fab fa-whatsapp"></i>', 'ico.Instagram': '<i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>', 'ico.Google': '<i class="fab fa-google"></i>', 'ico.Microsoft': '<i class="fab fa-microsoft"></i>', 'ico.Twitter': '<i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>', 'ico.Facebook': '<i class="fab fa-facebook"></i>', };

const replaceIco = (str) => {
  return str
    .split(' ')
    .map((s) => iconMap[s] ?? s)
    .join(' ');
};

const userText = 'ico.Whatsapp WhatsApp ico.Win10 Windows + S';

const keysArray = userText.split('+').map(replaceIco);

console.log(keysArray);
```